# CMakeFiles Not included for Poco Net

Tags: c++, http, poco

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23.1)

project(Poco_client VERSION 0.1.0)

file(GLOB all_SRCS
    "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main.cpp"
)


add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${all_SRCS})

set( Poco "C:/Poco/Foundation/include")
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${Poco})
message(STATUS "Message was include libraries :" ${Poco} )


set(Net "C:/Poco/Net/include")
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${Net})
message(STATUS "Message was include libraries :" ${Net} )
```

**In main.cpp i included  Net Libraries**

```
#include <Poco/Net/SocketAddress.h>
#include <Poco/Net/StreamSocket.h>
#include <Poco/Net/SocketStream.h>
```

I am running code based on Cmakefiles.tcxt Every time it will giving linker error.

LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'PocoFoundationd.lib' [C:\fwdcheckerboardandyaml\poco_server\build\Poco_se
rver.vcxproj]

In my poco downloads there is no lib files.

Then how can I add Net to poco libraries in CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: Perhaps you downloaded the wrong Poco package? Since you seem to build with MSVC you must download and install MSVC-specific libraries.

Comment: Or build them from the poco source code if they aren't provided

Comment: PocoFoundationd.dll error showing , After reinstalling

Comment: The code execution cannot proceed because PocoFoundationd.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem.     It means i want to reinstall the VSCOde community.

Comment: No it means you have installed the DLL files in a non-standard location, and that you need to update your `PATH` environment variable to include the location of the DLL files.

Comment: yes i add but still  same error

Comment: Anybody help me to download POCO library for C++

Comment: When I am using Poco/Net libraries It giving error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48592559